# How to grep a string value from info.plist file?

Tags: ios, shell, command-line, grep

Here is an example iOS info.plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>178273</string>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How can I grep the string value 178273 from this file from the command line? This 178273 can be a different number. The goal is to grep this value under the key CFBundleVersion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example:

```
cat info.plist | grep -A1 "CFBundleVersion" | grep -o "[0-9]*"
```

Assumption

- The target must be on the line immediately following key CFBundleVersion.
- Target must be a number. Others must not contain numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A plist file is XML, so you should be using tools that understand XML, not text-oriented tools like `grep`. In this case, something that can apply an XPath expression to a document and print out the matching data. Example using the common `xmllint` utility:

```bash
$ xmllint --xpath '/plist/dict/key[text()="CFBundleVersion"]/following::string[1]/text()' info.plist
178273
```

Comment: It works, but it gives an extra symbol % at the end. 178273%

Comment: @s-hunter That's just your shell saying the output to the terminal doesn't end in a newline. Presumably you're setting a variable or using it in a pipeline in real use where that doesn't really matter.